# Android-Sending sms from android application

Tags: android

This is my code.I have added permission in manifest file but then my app is unfortunately stopped.Why is it so?
If i had try catch,catch part is getting executed.

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.telephony.SmsManager;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    public class SendSMSActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
EditText eTextMsg, eTextMblNumber;
Button btnSendSMS;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    eTextMblNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etextMblNumber);
    eTextMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etextMsg);
    btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSendSMS);
    btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            sendSMS();
        }
    });
}
public void sendSMS()
{
    SmsManager sm = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String number = eTextMblNumber.getText().toString();
    String msg = eTextMsg.getText().toString();
    sm.sendTextMessage(number, null, msg, null, null);
}
```

Comment: "catch part is getting executed" - please share the Exception message

Comment: Have you added SEND_SMS permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file ? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

Comment: thank u both for replying.I got it at last.Since i am using marshmallow , i need to use requestpermission() which i didn't use.Now i finally got it.